# get key/value pair from json response object in angular 2 typescript

Tags: json, angular, angular2-services, key-value

```
 return this._http.post(apiUrl, model)
            .map((res: Response) => {
                console.log(res.json());
                let user = res.json();
               //let user = Object.keys(res.json());   <-- only gives keys not values

                if (user) {
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        })
```

this is my post method ...

this is console output ...

```
Object {Id: 101, UserName: "appatel", FirstName: "aarsh", LastName: "patel", Password: "aarsh"…}
Email: "aarshpatel@gmail.com"
FirstName: "aarsh"
Gender: "Male  "
Id: 101
LastName: "patel"
Password: "aarsh"
UserName: "appatel"
```

I want to set username in local storage ..
How can I do that ??

Comment: You should not do in in map.

Comment: Why ??  Any reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set Data :**

```
let user = res.json();
if (user) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
}
```

**Fetch data :**

```
if(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
    let user_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    console.log(user_data);
    console.log(user_data.UserName);
}
```

Comment: Here you are setting localstorage item as whole 'user' data and while getting you use 'username'

I can't understand that

Comment: There are 2 console.log , first will console log whole user object and second will just username

Comment: @Aarsh, sorry for typo , please check again

Comment: Yupp its working.
But why I can't directly set username ??
Why after fetch the data and then set ??
I want to directly set username in localstorage

Comment: You can also do that just use localStorage.setItem('username', user['UserName']));  and then localStorage.getItem('username').

Comment: In set or fetch ??

Comment: first in set , second in fetch

Answer (score 1):

Just access the property UserName,

```
if (user) {
     localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user.UserName));
}
```

Comment: how do you say?

Comment: localStorage
Storage {currentUser: "undefined"}

Comment: print console.log(JSON.stringify(user)) and post here

Comment: {"Id":101,"UserName":"appatel","FirstName":"aarsh","LastName":"patel","Password":"aarsh","Gender":"Male  ","Email":"aarshpatel@gmail.com"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157267/discussion-between-aarsh-and-sajeetharan).